# mysql: сравнение значения поля со значениями из вложенных запросов (count)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

подскажите пожалуйста как разобраться со следующей ситуацией:

есть таблица t1, в которой я вычисляю кол-во записей по определённым критериям

```
select count(*) from t1 where t1.f1 = t1.f2
```

результат гарантированно - 1 запись

а дальше в другом запросе мне надо использовать этот запрос и сравнить значение с полем

```
select * from t2 where t2.f3 > (select count(*) from t1 where t1.f1 = t1.f2)
```

но такой запрос ругается на множество полей во вложенном запросе
единственное, что помогает - это если вместо сравнения использовать `IN` и это подошло бы, если бы мне нужно было равенство, но мне нужна более сложная логика (минимум больше-меньше), как быть?

Comment: [Не воспроизводится.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4iJntrezjzTymXpWk2Gopd/0)  Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Ainar-G, модифицировал https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4iJntrezjzTymXpWk2Gopd/2, и все работает, кхм, проверил локально - тоже работает :( похоже я рано поспешил писать вопрос -наверное дело в том, что изначально у меня действительно выдавалось по `select`несколько записей, а когда я скорректировал условия, то стала выдаваться только одна и все заработало